# PHP JavaScript HTML Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

Okay, I have looked high and low and can't seem to find anything QUITE like this. I have found pieces but am unable to get them to work together.

Page 1: User Inputs Form Data
Page 2: User Confirms Data (PHP Sessions called "FullName" & "FieldInfo" start)
Page 3: Information is inserted into MySQL DB and Session "FieldInfo" is destroyed.
ALSO on Page 3 there is HTML code that displays a disclaimer, at the bottom of that disclaimer I have a text field with the name "FullNameSign". This is going to act as a "Signature" field for the person to temporarily "sign" this disclaimer (until it can be mailed to them). Now, here is where my problem begins. I want a script to redirect
IF $_SESSION['FullName'] equals FullNameSign
Redirect to Page4.php,
Else have a message saying, "Sign the form field"

Basically, it is doing NOTHING. It literally just sits there and does nothing, no error, no fail, no nothing!
Ok, I don't really want to post my code because I am a noob to PHP and I know that I am probably going overboard with stuff or don't need to do some of the stuff, so don't bust me up too bad ;-) I have only been doing PHP for like a week lol, that being said, here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/Styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/jQStyles.css">
<script src="../Scripts/Styles.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/StateComplete.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/datepick.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/SelectorYN.js"></script>
<script>
var FullNameTest = <?php echo $_SESSION['FullNameTest'];?>
function Accept()
if (FullNameTest = FullNameSign) {
window.location.href = 'page4.php';
} else {
greeting = "Please Sign";
}
</script>
<?php

//Session
session_start(NameInfo);
session_start(FormInfo);
$Today = date("m d Y");

// Table Information
$dbhost = 'xxxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxx';
$dbname = 'xxxx';


// Make Connection
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Check Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Applicants(
Userid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
MName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
LName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Street1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Street2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
State VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Zip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DOB VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PriPh VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
SecPh VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PPYN VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PPN VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PPED VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PPAD VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Emp VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Occ VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMRel VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMPriPh VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMSecPh VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMStrt1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMStrt2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMCity VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMState VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMZip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
EMEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Userid)
)";

// Create Table If it doesn't exist
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
echo "Table created successfully";
}

// Escape Variables
$FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['FName']);
$MName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['MName']);
$LName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['LName']);
$Street1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Street1']);
$Street2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Street2']);
$City = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['City']);
$State = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['State']);
$Zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Zip']);
$Gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Gender']);
$DOB = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['DOB']);
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Email']);
$PriPh = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['PriPh']);
$SecPh = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['SecPh']);
$PPYN = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['PPYN']);
$PPN = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['PPN']);
$PPED = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['PPED']);
$PPAD = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['PPAD']);
$Emp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Emp']);
$Occ = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['Occ']);
$EMName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMName']);
$EMRel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMRel']);
$EMPriPh = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMPriPh']);
$EMSecPh = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMSecPh']);
$EMStrt1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMStrt1']);
$EMStrt2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMStrt2']);
$EMCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMCity']);
$EMState = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMState']);
$EMZip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMZip']);
$EMEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['EMEmail']);

// Insert Form Fields into MySQL
$sql="INSERT INTO Applicants (FName, MName, LName, Street1, Street2, City, State, Zip, Gender, DOB, Email, PriPh, SecPh, PPYN, PPED, PPAD, Emp, Occ, EMName, EMRel, EMPriPh, EMSecPh, EMStrt1, EMStrt2, EMCity, EMState, EMZip, EMEmail)
VALUES ('$FName','$MName','$LName','$Street1','$Street2','$City','$State','$Zip','$Gender','$DOB','$Email','$PriPh','$SecPh','$PPYN','$PPED','$PPAD','$Emp','$Occ','$EMName','$EMRel','$EMPriPh','$EMSecPh','$EMStrt1','$EMStrt2','$EMCity','$EMState','$EMZip','$EMEmail')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Success";

//Close Connection
mysqli_close($con);

//Destroy FormInfo Session
session_destroy(FormInfo);
?>
<title>SALT, Inc. Mission Application Personal Information</title>
</head>
<body id="application">
<div id="divheader">
<div class="header1">
<img src="/Images/Logo.jpg" align="left" style="padding-left: 150px">
</div>
<div class="header2">

</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="head-nav">
<ul id="nav-list">
<li id="active">
<a href="" id="homenav">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" id="aboutnav">About Us</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" id="contactnav">Contact</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" id="applicationnav">Become A Missionary</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" id="projectnav">Projects</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="" id="donatenav">Donations</a>
</li>
<li>    
<a href="" id="linksnav">Links</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<div align="center" id="headertext">
<b>Short Term Mission Application</b></div>
<br>
<div style="padding-left: 20px">
<center><b>MEDICAL RELEASE</b><br><br>
*Disclaimer is contained here*
Applicant’s signature: <form><input type="text" name="FullNameSign"><br><br>
Date: <?php echo $Today;?><br><br>
<input type="button" onClick="Accept()" value="Next"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, in advance, for any help

Comment: It would probably help to start with valid PHP. No idea why you're doing `session_start` twice in a row, and `session_start(NameInfo)` isn't PHP - it'd either be `session_start($NameInfo)` or `session_start('NameInfo')`, but `session_start` doesn't even *take* any parameters at all. Where are you learning this syntax?

Comment: I have 2 session starts because I have one session that keeps all the info from the Form 2 pages back and the other takes the users First Middle and Last Name and makes it their Full Name. That I want to carry across like 4 more pages.
I didn't realize that was how they needed named, I figured it was like naming a function, it is however, working. Like when I call on FullName down in the disclaimer, it will display what I tell it to. I will fix that though

Comment: If this is your first week of PHP, maybe start with something simpler. I don't think you understand sessions, for one thing, or how CGI variables work. Write a page that takes one parameter and prints `Hello <name>`. Then make it more complex. Don't try to do everything at once. Test as you go.

Comment: And you may want to read up on:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: Im not trying to sound dumb here, but I actually like starting with a complex project and learn how to do the stuff as I progress, I feel like I learn better like that than just reading. That's why I started like I did. Thanks for the advice, I will read up more on the sessions. I tried to read up on them, but everything I read seems like it is so dumbed down, and it doesn't really tell me much about starting them. Apparently, I need to refer to another page

Comment: To expand on what @ceejayoz said, you only need to call `session_start()` once at the top of your page. To save session information you would use `$_SESSION['NameInfo'] = 'John Doe';` or whatever you're trying to save. Then you can recall that information by using just `$_SESSION['NameInfo']` which in this case would give you John Doe

Comment: I understand that, I think. This is my ACTUAL session starts on the "confirm" page:

session_start(NameInfo);
$_SESSION['FullName'] = $_POST['FName'].' '.$_POST['MName'].' '.$_POST['LName'];

session_start(FormInfo);
$_SESSION['FName'] =  $_POST['FName'];
$_SESSION['MName'] =  $_POST['MName'];

The reason I have 2 is because "NameInfo" will carry across like 4 or more pages more and as soon as all of the form fields are placed into the DB, "FormInfo" is destroyed, on the page that I am working on.

Comment: PHP can only have one session going at a time, and you don't need to name it. Passing a parameter to session_start is completely useless. The names come in at the `$_SESSION['name']` part. So only one `session_start()`, and no parameters. Using `session_destroy()` will delete ALL of your session data that you set on this page. If you want to delete specific `$_SESSION[]` info, use `unset($_SESSION['name']);`

Comment: Also regarding your original problem, `var FullNameTest = <?php echo $_SESSION['FullNameTest'];?>` should be `var FullNameTest = "<?php echo $_SESSION['FullNameTest'];?>";`. That way javascript recognizes the variable FullNameTest as a string and when you compare it later at this line: `if (FullNameTest == FullNameSign) {` it will work as expected (assuming FullNameSign is a string aswell). The way you had it, javascript would be trying to set var FullNameTest to another variable named whatever `$_SESSION['FullNameTest']` was returning, which obviously doesn't exist. Hope you understand that.

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code though that will need to be worked out before it will work as expected as well. Too many to go over on this comment section, but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some highlites of some other problems.
BTW:
    http://www.php.net/function.session-start 
will tell you everything you want to know about session_start();
and
    http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php
will tell you everything you want to know about session_destroy();

In your lines like:
    $FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['FName']);
Perhaps I missed it, but the setting of that session variable seems to be missing
And
before using a session (or post or get) variable, a check should be performed to assure that variable is actually set and contains some value.
This can be done like this:
    if( isset($_SESSION['FName']) && false != $_SESSION['FName'] )
    {
        $FName = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_SESSION['FName'] );
    }
    else
    {
        $FName = 'dummy value'; // set some reasonable value, so the query does not cause a crash in the DB query
}
This kind of existence checking should be done for each of the session variables.

I notice the variable 
    $Today 
is being accessed, but I do not see where it is being set.
The following will tell you all you need to know about obtaining a date value
    http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

If you run your code through some syntax checker, like tidy 
    http://tidy.sourceforge.net/
most of the syntax, html tag pairing, and similar such opps will be remarked upon, to make them easy to spot/correct.

Please apply the above information, then edit the code.  Then we can assist you with the basic problem that you want answered.
Most importantly, please clarify the explanation of what you want the code to do.
Without such clarification, I/we have only a vague idea as to which way to direct you in fixing the code.